# Content of Element Declaration Must Match and Other Validation Errors

Tags: xml, xsd

I am very new to XML and Schema and am having a really hard time trying to validate my document. I keep getting the error that Content of Element Declaration Must Match at line 13 column 58. I have tried everything I can possibly think of and read every article and other question and can't figure it out. Please help!

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CustomerAccount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" LastUpdated="2011-12-01" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="me.xsd">

  <UpdatedBy kind="SalesPerson">Lisa Moroz</UpdatedBy>

  <ShipTo country="Canada">
    <name>Maya Wells</name>
    <street>44 Gamble Avenue</street>
    <city>Toronto</city>
    <province>ON</province>
    <zip>L1M3G1</zip>
  </ShipTo>

  <ShipTo country="Canada">
    <name>Maya Wells</name>
    <street>62 Elm Street</street>
    <city>Montreal</city>
    <province>QC</province>
    <zip>K2J3H4</zip>
  </ShipTo>

  <BillTo>
    <country>Canada</country>
    <name>Maya Wells</name>
    <street>78 Audley Street</street>
    <city>Oakville</city>
    <province>ON</province>
    <zip>O3R1M5</zip>
  </BillTo>

</CustomerAccount>
```

And here is my Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="CustomerAccount">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:element name="UpdatedBy" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ShipTo" type="ShipToType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="BillTo" type="BillToType" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name ="kind" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>


  <xs:complexType name="ShipToType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="province" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="zip" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="country" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="BillToType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="province" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="zip" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:sequence> 
  </xs:complexType>


</xs:schema>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `CustomerAccount` element definition should be modified that way:

```
<xs:element name="CustomerAccount">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="UpdatedBy">
                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:attribute name ="kind" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ShipTo" type="ShipToType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="BillTo" type="BillToType" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="LastUpdated" type="xs:date"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```